# How can a class have constructors taking const or non-const paramter?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a wrapper class that can modify or get the value of its field object. The class may accept const or non-const argument.

I tried to have two different constructor, but the second one that takes const parameter is throwing error saying the const qualifier is droped.

Here is the demo.
https://godbolt.org/z/3n8acjx3v

```
struct A {
    int a;
};

struct B {
    B(A& a) : a_(a){};
    B(const A& a) : a_(a){};   // throwing exception
    A& getA() & { return a_; }

    A& a_;
};

int main() {
    A a{};
    const A ca{};
    B b {a};
    const B cb{ca};
}
```

I was wondering how can I fix it? What's the best practice if I want to implement a accessor class like this one?

Comment: The simplest solution is to have two classes, `B` and `ConstB`. This is the solution adopted by the standard library for iterators (there are separate `iterator` and `const_iterator` types for all containers).

Comment: A reference to a const type and a reference to a type are two different kind of references. Why do you expect `A&` to be bound to `const A&`?

Comment: Of course `A& a_;` cannot be bound to `const A& a`. That will only result in a compile time error.

Comment: **throwing exception** is something that happens in runtime. Compiler errors are not runtime exceptions.

Comment: So there is no way to have one class that supports both const getter and non-const setter functions?

Comment: @LunaticJape if you function signature says that it takes a `const &A`, it tells the client code that whatever is passed won't be changed. By removing constness of the reference you violate the contract

Comment: The whole idea of this wrapper class seems a bit weird to me.  You're inviting a dangling reference, for one thing.  What's the use-case?